# Kids that fight troll-like monsters with water guns filled with milk?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember watching this kids movie where they are being attacked by some sort of trollish type monsters/creatures and they could only be defeated by using water guns filled with milk to shoot them with. I remember that pretty distinctly but the rest of the movie I have no clue.

I could tell you I saw this in the 90's but I have no idea how old the movie actually is, nor other plot descriptions, apart from that there was an epic battle between the kids and the trollish creatures where they were victorious in thanks to the milk powered water guns (sounds ridiculously hilarious I know).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems like the plot to *Ernest Scared Stupid*

[**IMDB**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101821/combined)

[**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Scared_Stupid) has a very full plot description that matches all your criteria. Here's a key line: *Kenny and the others launch a defensive and manage to destroy all of the trolls except for Trantor who becomes too powerful to be affected by milk.*